# MSSQL Ошибка арифметического переполнения при преобразовании expression к типу данных smalldatetime.

Tags: sql-server, sql

Создал представление, содержащее следующий запрос:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.заявки_рас.ДатаПоступления + dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления AS datetime_add, dbo.дома.УК AS uk, 
               dbo.заявки_рас.ВидРабот AS type_work
FROM  dbo.дома INNER JOIN
               dbo.заявки_рас ON dbo.дома.АдресДома = dbo.заявки_рас.АдресДома
WHERE (dbo.заявки_рас.ОтметкаУдалить = 0) AND (dbo.заявки_рас.ЗаявкаВыполнена = 1) OR
               (dbo.заявки_рас.ОтметкаУдалить IS NULL)
ORDER BY datetime_add
```

И в результате получаю ошибку, упомянутую в сабже. В mssql разбираюсь плохо, подскажите где искать проблему? Индексов в таблице "заявки_рас" нету (сначала думал из за них, тк все началось после операций с пересозданием индекса).
Если убрать

```
dbo.заявки_рас.ДатаПоступления + dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления AS datetime_add,
```

...то вроде работает, но для правильного результата необходимо всетаки сложить эти два времени.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что у вас колонки `dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления` и `dbo.заявки_рас.ДатаПоступления` имеют тип `smalldatetime`. Чтобы не было такой ошибки, нужно привести данные к типу `datetime`.

Но меня немного смущает метод сложения дат.

Пример. Дата 2007-05-08 12:35:00 + дата '2007-05-08 14:35:00 выдаст 2114-09-13 03:10:00.000, то есть складываются все составляющие дат.

Возможно, тут лучше использовать [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx) метод.

Comment: Функцию dateadd, я полагаю.

Comment: Да, моя опечатка, думала о dateadd, а написала datediff. Только придется добавлять по компоненту времени за раз:
dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления), dateadd(minute, datepart(minute, dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления), dateadd(second, datepart(second, dbo.заявки_рас.ВремяПоступления), dbo.заявки_рас.ДатаПоступления)))

Возможно, стоит задуматься о том, чтобы хранить время в более удобном формате:

 -- Тип данных time в SQL Server 2008;
 -- время и минуты перевести в секунды и хранить суммарное кол-во секунд;

Comment: В результате сложения
'2011.09.18 00:00:00' и '1900:01:01 12:51:10'
получаем '2011.09.18 12:51:10', т.е. все верно, использовать dateadd нет необходимости. А типа данных date или time отдельно, в sql express 2005 - я не нашел.. Пришлось прибегнуть к такому вот "кривому" варианту. Это было года три назад, когда в базах данных я не понимал ровно ничего, и все работало, пока сейчас вот не вылезло боком :)